# Existence of a MooTools class for labels / tags / keywords splitting

Tags: input, mootools, tagging

Does anyone know of a MooTools class that provides an input splitter for labels, or “tags”?

The same kind of functionality as [Tagify](http://projects.alicialiu.net/jquery-tagify-demo/) in jQuery.

Googling is especially tricky for something with “tag”, “label”, “keyword”… And nor the Forge nor GitHub have anything looking close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so the last 30 mins don't go to waste, I released my tag plugin on github.

https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/mooTagify

demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/6X7Yb/

it lacks autocomplete at the moment but that's already available, I will add it when I get a chance.

features:

- support for min chars, max chars (on tag)
- maximum tags
- disallows duplicates
- events

Comment: Thanks for releasing this Dimitar :)

Comment: no worries. watch on github for when I add mooTagify.autoComplete

Answer (score 3):

http://mootools.net/forge/p/textboxlist

It's a little old and Guillermo Rauch (the developer) is not maintaining it (he's mainly working on cool stuff for node.js atm), but it should work pretty well.

Demo here: http://devthought.com/wp-content/projects/mootools/textboxlist/Demo/

Comment: cool stuff for node.js - yeaaah, right. :D I have written one that behaves more loosely, but it needs work as standalone - in production, its an event driven mixin - it lacks public property for tags as it uses DOM storage: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/6X7Yb/ - supports comma separation, min length, max length, max number of tags, duplicate tags are NOT ALLOWED, etc.

Comment: it also had support for "special tags" like public, private etc. but i stripped that out (for the most part). maybe someday i will release it on the forge. maybe not.

Comment: ha, good stuff Dimitar :) ...yea u should release it ;) or just put a repo on github so devs/we can contribute ;)

Comment: it's too niche to release though I may have a go, the annoying bit is having to document it, style it and provide examples. i have now added a public method `getTags()` - it's all I'll ever need :x

Comment: Thanks! I haven't validated this answer since TextBoxList is 1.2-compatible, not so readable and is not very clear about its licensing. It is probably more future-proof to link to a GitHub repo. I really had searched the Forge, did the whole “Interface” and “Forms” categories, but did not think about “Widgets”…